# Using dictionaries to improve algorithm efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The nth triangle number is defined as the sum 1+2+...+n. I'm working on [Project Euler problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) which asks to find the smallest triangle number that has over 500 divisors, so (in Python) I wrote two functions, `mytri(n)` and `mydiv(n)`, to compute the nth triangle number, and the number of divisors of n, respectively. Then, I used a while loop that iterates until `mydiv(mytri(n))` is greater than or equal to 500:

```
import math

def mytri(n):
    return n*(n+1)/2

def mydivs(n):
    num = 0
    max = math.floor(n/2)
    for k in range(1,max+1):
        if n%k == 0: 
            num += 1
    return num+1

n = 1
while (mydivs(mytri(n)) <= 500): n += 1

print(mytri(n))
```

I thought I wrote `mytri()` and `mydiv()` pretty efficiently, but based on some tests, it seems like this program gets unwieldy very quickly. To compute the first number with over 100 divisors takes less than a second, but to compute the first number with over 150 divisors takes about 8-9 seconds, indicating that it's probably exponential in time? I don't have much experience with computational complexity or writing efficient algorithms but I once saw an example of using dictionaries (memoization I think?) to greatly improve a recursive algorithm to compute the Fibonacci numbers, and I was wondering if a similar idea could be used here.

For example, the nth triangle number can be expressed as n(n+1)/2, so without loss of generality it's the product of an odd and even number, say n and (n+1)/2 respectively. If you could store the divisors for each number up to n in a dictionary, then you wouldn't have to redo the computations in `mydiv()`, and instead you could just reference the dictionary. The only issue is finding out which divisors between n and (n+1)/2 overlap to get the right number of them. Is this a reasonable line of attack? Or am I missing something here?

Additionally, what is the time complexity of my algorithm and how would I calculate it?

Comment: You can't really use any memory because you always use other n. (as far as I can see). Fibonacci it works because `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` it has a recursion and if you calculate `F(50)` you will calculate `F(30)` multiple times and therefore you can use a memory. You should probably start with thinking about another algorithm which is more efficient.

Comment: @goodatthis check the answer I posted. I might help you.

Comment: @goodatthis Please accept the answer if it helped you. It will help the community at large in identifying the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mytri(n)`'s Time complexity is `O(1)`. `mydivs(n)`'s time complexity is `O(n/2)` which is `O(n)`.`while (mydivs(mytri(n)) <= 500)`'s time complexity is `O(n^3)` since it is loop inside a loop, one loop runs *N* times and other runs *N^2* times.. You can reduce the `mydivs(n)`'s time complexity to `O(sqrt(n)`.

```
def new_mydivs(n):
    res=set()
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)+1):
        #print(i)
        if n%i==0:
            res.update([i,n//i])
        #print(res)
    return len(res)    #returns the number of divisors.
```

### The time complexity of `new_mydivs(n)` is `O(sqrt(n))`.

## Your code performance time for finding a number with 250 divisors.

```
import time
import timeit
import math
def mytri(n):
    return n*(n+1)/2
def mydivs(n):
    num = 0
    max = math.floor(n/2)
    for k in range(1,max+1):
        if n%k == 0: 
            num += 1
    return num+1

def main():
    n = 1
    while (mydivs(mytri(n)) <= 250): n += 1

    print(mytri(n))

startTime=time.time()
main()
print(time.time()-startTime)
```

output:

```
2162160.0
100.24735450744629
```

---

## My code performance time for 250 divisors:

```
import time
import timeit
import math
def mytri(n):
    return n*(n+1)/2
def mydivs(n):
    res=set()
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)+1):
        #print(i)
        if n%i==0:
            res.update([i,n//i])
        #print(res)
    return len(res)    #returns the number of divisors.

def main():
    n = 1
    while (mydivs(mytri(n)) <= 250): n += 1

    print(mytri(n))

startTime=time.time()
main()
print(time.time()-startTime)
```

output:

```
2162160.0
0.22459840774536133
```

## for 500 divisors:

```
76576500.0
5.7917985916137695
```

## for 750 divisors:

```
236215980.0
17.126375198364258
```

See the performance increased drastically.

Comment: the original complexity is O(N^3), you reduced it to O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

RE: time complexity. You have two loops one inside another, one running up to N, another running up to N^2. This gives us the O(N^3) time complexity.

You may use dictionaries to save the partial result, but the overall complexity will still be O(N^3), however with a smaller constant factor, because you still have to loop over the rest of the values.

Comment: which partial results? as far as I can see there is no value that he calculate twice.